# Usage of Correct T-Test

Tags: t-test

I am conducting a case-control study and hoping to look for significant differences in the mean of my dependent variable. The design of my approach incorporated 1:1 matching of controls to cases based on several characteristics. Is an independent samples T-test appropriate in this regard? Total participants in the study are n=90 (45 cases, 45 controls).

Thank you!